# Incrementing a class in a custom walker

Tags: walker

I have written a custom walker that I am using with `wp_nav_menu` but I need to iterate through 4 custom classes, and I'm not sure how to do this. Basically, each menu-item `<li>` needs to be given a class of `color1`, `color2`, `color3` or `color4`, cycling back to `color1`, lather, rinse, repeat, in that order.

Ordinarily I would do this with a `$i` and a `$i++`, but how do I do this in the Walker class?

EDIT: My Walker class code:

```
class Salamander_Advent_Walker extends Walker_page {
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    if ( $depth ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    } else {
        $indent = '';
    }

    $advent_thumbnail = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-thumb', true);
    $advent_slug = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-slug', true);
    $advent_oneliner = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-oneliner', true);
    //$description = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-thumb', true);

    $output .= $indent . '
    <li class="active color4">
        <a href="#day'. $advent_slug .'">
            <span class="day">
                <strong>'. $advent_slug .'</strong>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
            <span class="content">
                <small>'. $advent_slug .'</small>
                <img src='. $advent_thumbnail .' width="126" height="91" alt="advent" />
                <strong>'. $advent_oneliner .'</strong>
            </span>
        </a>';                      
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class variable to keep the 'index' of the colour you wish to display. Increment each time it's used, and check if it goes over, in which case set it back to 1.

```
class Salamander_Advent_Walker extends Walker_page {
    private $color_idx = 1;
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        if ( $depth ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        } else {
            $indent = '';
        }

        $advent_thumbnail = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-thumb', true);
        $advent_slug = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-slug', true);
        $advent_oneliner = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-oneliner', true);
        //$description = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-thumb', true);

        $output .= $indent . '
        <li class="active color'.$this->color_idx.'">
            <a href="#day'. $advent_slug .'">
                <span class="day">
                    <strong>'. $advent_slug .'</strong>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
                <span class="content">
                    <small>'. $advent_slug .'</small>
                    <img src='. $advent_thumbnail .' width="126" height="91" alt="advent" />
                    <strong>'. $advent_oneliner .'</strong>
                </span>
            </a>';              
        $this->color_idx++;
        if ($this->color_idx > 4) {
            $this->color_idx = 1
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate function:

```
function alternate()
{
    static $i = 0;
    $args = func_get_args();

    return $args[ $i++ % func_num_args() ];
}
```

In your walker use it like this:

```
$class = 'color' . alternate( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
// somewhere in your output string:
$output .= '<li class="active ' . $class . '">';
```

Comment: The static counter could also be a class var, same thing just less a function.

Comment: @MarkDuncan I am a fan of atomic functions: one function per task. It makes debugging so much easier. :)

Comment: Sounds logical, not sure i'd personally use a function for counting alone, but a valid approach nonetheless.

Comment: Sorry appendum, there's a problem with your sample code(the second sample is invalid, as is)...

Comment: @MarkDuncan How exactly?

Comment: Nice code, simple & cool!

Comment: @toscho - You're missing an echo/print or var declaration at the start of the second line.

Comment: @MarkDuncan The last line is obviously just an excerpt. I see no need to repeat the entire output. Our readers should _understand_, not just copy. :)

Comment: @toscho - Perhaps you could add that to the answer to make it clear, there could be some expectation for code posted as an answer to be a working sample(or noted otherwise). Yes we can expect developers/programmers to be here, but i don't think that's any reason to post invalid samples, even if some level of understanding is assumed... i personally just think samples should be valid wherever possible(of course, imho).

Comment: @MarkDuncan Point taken. I still have a strong opinion about people who just copy some code. They _should_ fail. It’s a good way to learn something. Anyway, I made my example more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting the incrementing number to a global variable.

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    //globalize the variable
    global $ac_color_num;
    //check if it is set, or if it is 4 (to reset to 1)
    if ( !isset($ac_color_num) || $ac_color_num == 4 ) { $ac_color_num = 1; }
    $ac_color_num++
    if ( $depth ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    } else {
        $indent = '';
    }

    $advent_thumbnail = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-thumb', true);
    $advent_slug = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-slug', true);
    $advent_oneliner = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-oneliner', true);
    //$description = get_post_meta($item->ID, 'advent-thumb', true);

    //use $ac_color_num in the output.
    $output .= $indent . '
    <li class="active color' . $ac_color_num . '">
        <a href="#day'. $advent_slug .'">
            <span class="day">
                <strong>'. $advent_slug .'</strong>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
            <span class="content">
                <small>'. $advent_slug .'</small>
                <img src='. $advent_thumbnail .' width="126" height="91" alt="advent" />
                <strong>'. $advent_oneliner .'</strong>
            </span>
        </a>';                      
}
```

Comment: There're already _too many_ globals and conflicts are just about to happen. If you add a global, then only if you _really_ have to and even then, you should prefix it.

Comment: Fair enough. The other answer is more elegant, but mine still solves the problem - not sure if it warrants a downvote... I will say that the likelihood of $color_num conflicting is really low, especially in the scope of any process that this walker would be run in.

Comment: When using globals, then there's no "scope" - it's called global for a reason :) Possible conflicts could be color pickers. Add a prefix and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: By scope I meant the entire process. Added prefix ac_ for 'amanda custom'. Thanks.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Instead of calling `get_post_meta()` several times, you can also do `extract( get_post_custom( $post->ID ), EXTR_SKIP );` which gives you the same vars you used with a simple one-liner. Oh, and you're missing a space between the classes: `"active color' . $ac_color_num . '"`.

Comment: That's a nice move with get_post_custom - I was just doing a copypasta of her code and adding my stuff in. the lack of a space is so the class is color3 instead of color 3 - I'm just outputting the number.